# Hair particles on a moving and deforming mesh sequence

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, particles, hair

I have a .ply sequence of 10 frames (from a fluid simulation) imported with [Stop-motion-OBJ](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ) which looks like this:

[image]

The mesh is constantly having a change in the number of vertices/faces as it is deforming.

Now, I want the hair particles to behave as strands attached to these moving faces and follow the motion of the mesh. Something like this:

[image]

I did try a basic hair particle system and before that I did the following as well:

- Cleaned the imported mesh( removed doubles/recalculate normals)
- Created a particle system on frame 1 Checked `Use Modifier Stack`
- I also turned the stiffness down to a super low value.
- Physics set to Newtonian and the rest pretty much the default.

This results in:

[image]

I notice two problems immediately. First, the hair particles are still rigid and stiff and two, beyond frame #10, nothing happens except that they continue to remain stiff.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to go about doing this as I am new to modeling particle systems in blender. Any pointers are appreciated.